# Google App Engine encoding

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding

I'm trying to log some russian text:

```
LOG.info("тестирование русского");
```

But I get question symbols instead (viewing from web):

> [app-id/app-version].:
>   15:18:44,753 INFO  [class] -
>   ???????????? ????????

Java file saved with UTF-8 encoding. All settings are default.

Even I read file in UTF-8 with russian characters and try to log something from it -- encoding is wrong too.

Comment: have you tried to send the text as a unicode type of string?

Comment: Good to know what the default `Charset` is on GAE (apparently, ASCII), which I *believe* is a modified Jetty instance running on their own flavor or Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Hebrew text. I found out it was caused by the default encoding.

To check the default encoding, I used this code:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
String encoding = out.getEncoding();
```

On my computer, the encoding is "UTF8". On the GAE server, it is "ASCII".

I solved the problem by replacing all the file readers in my code with:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

This tells Java to ignore the default encoding, and open all input files as UTF8.

Comment: Cool, I've tried a lot of different approaches, but this one was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Apparently GAE tries to autodetect encoding and fails.
Even constant strings were messed up

```
public class Util {
    public static String FixRussianString(String string){
        try {
            return new String(string.getBytes("CP1251"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```